# Questdb docker StaticContentProcessor [106] not found

Tags: docker, websocket, questdb

I'm running questdb via docker on Linux (Ubuntu)

```
sudo docker run -p 9000:9000 questdb/questdb
```

and want to record some price data in python: from cryptofeed I use the example
https://github.com/bmoscon/cryptofeed/blob/master/examples/demo_questdb.py; the only change is that I send it to

```
QUEST_PORT = 9009
```

It seems it correctly sends it to the websocket but no tables appear in questdb. Looking at the terminal I constantly see messages of the form

```
i.q.c.h.p.StaticContentProcessor [101] incoming [url=price=23016.43,amount=4.344e-05,id=502741314i,receipt_timestamp=1677335290635411t]
i.q.c.h.p.StaticContentProcessor [101] not found [path=/var/lib/questdb/public/price=23016.43,amount=4.344e-05,id=502741314i,receipt_timestamp=1677335290635411t]
```

which looks like data is correctly send but something goes wrong with the database location. I don't see any tables being created on the questdb site (localhost:9000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run QuestDB docker with ILP port 9009 mapped

```bash
docker run \
  -p 9000:9000 -p 9009:9009 -p 8812:8812 -p 9003:9003 \
  questdb/questdb
```

Port 9000 is for REST HTTP requests, your log messages suggest that you send the data to port 9000 instead of 9009.

https://questdb.io/docs/get-started/docker/